# jQuery scroll to bottom of element not top

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, smooth-scrolling

I am using the following to scroll to an element

```
$("html, body").animate({
  scrollTop: $('selector').offset().top
}, 500);
```

The above code places the element at the top of the browser window when scrolled to it, is there a way I can scroll to the element with the scroll ending with the element at the bottom of the browser window?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the height of the [window](http://api.jquery.com/height/) to calculate your scroll position

Answer (score 17):

Try something like this to put the scroll at the bottom of the element

```
$("html, body").animate({
      scrollTop: $('selector').offset().top + $('selector').outerHeight(true)
    }, 500);
```

Or this to put the element at the bottom of the scroll:

```
$("html, body").animate({
          scrollTop: $('selector').offset().top + $('selector').outerHeight(true) -$(window).height()
        }, 500);
```

Comment: worked with some modification: `$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $('selector').offset().top - ($(window).height()-$("selector").outerHeight() +10)}, 500);`